# Dual-monitor seems to be default in Ubuntu 14.04, and I try to solve it, but close the wrong monitor

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, monitor, xrandr

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
My mouse goes outside the screen when moving to the right edge, so I guess something wrong with my monitor setting. lt seemed that "dual monitor" was set as default setting.
I ran the monitor app trying to turn off the virtual monitor, but I chose the wrong one and turned off the one I was using. 
All of a sudden, the screen became totally black.
I then switched to my second workspace (ctrl+alt+F2 then startx). It worked fine. (all six workspaces worked expect the last one)

I read [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently) and tried the first solution - save xrandr commands in /.xprofile.

I tried it in the following steps:

1. In order to set monitors by clicking mouse, I connected another monitor to my computer.
2. I set my monitors right and save the xrandr command in ~/.xprofile
3. Unplug the monitor and reboot my computer

Nothing changed but I found... 
When connected-on this additional monitor, I saved the content of xrandr as /.xprofile. I then disconnected physically the monitor and reboot my computer. But when I look again at xrandr and /.xprofile after rebooting, there are slight differences between these two. The numeration is changed. I wonder if the system numerates my outputs automatically so that it cannot detect and match the right one.

This is what my /.xprofile looks like:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS2 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-0 connected
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
HDMI-1-0 disconnected
VGA-1-0 disconnected
  1366x768 (0x49)   72.0MHz
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1516 skew    0 clock   47.5KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  792           clock   60.0Hz
```

And my xrandr: ~$ xrandr -q

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-1 connected
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1280x720       59.9  
   1152x768       59.8  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   848x480        59.7  
   720x480        59.7  
   640x480        59.4  
HDMI-1-0 disconnected
VGA-1-1 disconnected
  1366x768 (0x49)   72.0MHz
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1516 skew    0 clock   47.5KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  776 total  792           clock   60.0Hz
```

Also, I’m so confused. Why are LVDS1 and LVDS-1-1 both connected?
And I’m sure LVDS1 is the one I’m using, since trying to rotate it works, but LVDS-1-1 doesn’t.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my steps? Or other method to set back my monitor?